# Why is probability of observed data ignored in MAP estimate?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood

In a MAP estimate:

$\pi_{MAP} = \underset{\pi}{\operatorname{argmax}} P(\pi\mid\chi)$

$=\underset{\pi}{\operatorname{argmax}} \frac{P(\chi\mid\pi)P(\pi)}{P(\chi)}$

$=\underset{\pi}{\operatorname{argmax}} P(\chi\mid\pi)P(\pi)$

How can the distribution $P(\chi)$ be discarded in the second step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason we can discard $P(\chi)$ is that it is not a function of $\pi$, so it doesn't matter in terms of finding the value of $\pi$ that maximizes the posterior probability, just as the constant $c$ doesn't matter in terms of finding the $\arg \min_x$ of $c(x-\theta)^2$.

It would matter if what we cared about was what the value of the maximum posterior probability was, but we don't, we only care that it *is* the maximum posterior probability, and what the value of $\pi$ is that corresponds to it.